# facebook redirect url gives blank page

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

This is the login page script.

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
//includes


$id = '[MY ID]';
$secret = '[MY SECRET CODE]';

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($id, $secret);
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('[redirect Page]');
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
echo "<a href = " . $loginUrl . ">Login With Facebook</a>";

?>
```

and this is the redirect page script.

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
session_start();
//includes


$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper();
try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch(\Exception $ex) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}
if ($session) {
  // Logged in
$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
$response = $request->execute();
    $graph = $response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
    echo "Hi " . $graph->getName();  


}


?>
```

when it redirects, it comes to my redirect page and gives a blank page. and the url which it gives is the following  :

```
http://redirectpage?code=[very long code.]
```

I want this to execute and show me the result.

```
echo "Hi " . $graph->getName();
```

Comment: do you have anything in your access or error logs to say your even hitting the page ?

Comment: yes it is hitting the page. it makes me allow the facebook application

Comment: So when you go back to your server and you see the whitepage do you have any errors ? seems to me your not displaying errors.

Comment: You need to debug your code, add a var_dump inside your Exception and before your session etc etc

Comment: no errors are displayed. i just put echo's on every exception and nothing is displayed.

Comment: so if you put a die('Here') right at the top and delete everything else do you see anything ?

Comment: Well then you must have an error somewhere in your code, you need to debug it really

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your redirect script, make sure the `redirect_uri` is set to the same as the login page:

```
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper();
```

should be:

```
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('[redirect Page]');
```

The SDK throws an error if the `redirect_uri` isn't the same as the origin page.